# need to add new field in osclass table

Tags: php, mysql, osclass

I am working on osclass project and am stuck on one problem from last week.

I have modified `oc_t_item` table and added a new field called `bool b_show_contactnumber`.

I have added the following code in `ItemActions.php`

```
'b_show_contactnumber'  => $aItem['showcontactNumber'],

$aItem['showcontactNumber']  = (Params::getParam('showcontactNumber') != '') ? 1 : 0;
```

Its not working; the item is not saving.

I have checked the value of `$aItem['showcontactNumber']` in the other field and value is passing.

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is adding a 'Custom Field', at admin panel you can insert 'Custom Fields' like a radio buttons (SHOW CONTACT NUMB/ NO SHOW CONTACT NUMB).

Or you can try to develop a plugin, a little guide here http://wiki.osclass.org/How_to_extend_fields.

During the develop you can activate debugging adding some defines at config.php file , [Developer section](http://wiki.osclass.org/index.php/Main_Page#Developers) you can find Debug PHP errors & Debug SQL queries

If you can avoid modify the core files, you can continue updating osclass without problems.

Comment: dear Carlos, but i want to modify the main table and modify the main core in addition and edit process.

Comment: @air the main problem is that if you modify the core you wouldn't be able to update OSClass for newer versions easily. I think that the best way is creating a plugin.